# Grow heap (frag case) during file reading with Scanner

Tags: java, android, dalvik

I'm trying to read a 140kbytes text file with java.util.Scanner class and I got a this message in DDMS

```
I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 10.202MB for 524304-byte allocation
```

Here the snippet code that I'm using:

```html
Scanner read = new Scanner(mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.questions_file));
        read.useDelimiter(";");
        String q=null;
        String a1=null;
        String a2=null;
        String a3=null;
        String a4=null;
        int qno=0;
        try {
            while (read.hasNext()) {

                q = read.next();
                a1 = read.next();
                a2 = read.next();
                a3 = read.next();
                a4 = read.next();
//                mLog(q, a1, a2, a3, a4);
                qno++;

            }

            read.close();

            mLog("There are ", String.valueOf(qno), " questions");
        }catch (Exception e){mLog(e.getMessage());}
```

Comment: The log is reporting that about 512KB of memory was allocated.  Was this unexpected?

Comment: Maybe isn't a memory issue... I tried to split the file in two files with the same size and the reading procedure fails only on the second file .... I've to try to read the file in other way...

Comment: I found the problem. I had a java.util.NoSuchElementException during the reading of the EOF.